# Adding different buttons to TableView

Tags: java, uitableview, javafx

I have discovered how to insert a button inside a row's TableView but I'm not sure how could I add different values for that button:

```
column
    .setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<GuiObject, Boolean>, TableCell<GuiObject, Boolean>>() {
                    @Override
                    public TableCell<GuiObject, Boolean> call(
                            TableColumn<GuiObject, Boolean> p) {

                        return new ButtonCell();
                    }

                });
```

Where ButtonCell is self implemented button for `TableCell<GuiObject, Boolean>`, but I want to be able to dynamically insert different buttons dependent on the row I am inserting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you access the TableView from java like this:

```
@FXML
TableView myTable;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    TableColumn<Item, String> firstColumn = new TableColumn<>("First Column");
    firstColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Item, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Item, String> p) {
            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue().column1);
        }
    });

    TableColumn<Item, String> secondColumn = new TableColumn<>("Second Column");
    secondColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Item, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Item, String> p) {
            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue().column2);
        }
    });

    TableColumn<Item, Button> buttonCol = new TableColumn<>("ButtonColumn");
    buttonCol.setSortable(false);
    buttonCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Item, Button>, ObservableValue<Button>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<Button> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Item, Button> features) {
            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(features.getValue().button);
        }
    });
    myTable.getColumns().add(buttonCol);
    myTable.getColumns().add(firstColumn);
    myTable.getColumns().add(secondColumn);
    myTable.getItems().add(new Item("Test 1", "Test 1", new Button("Test 1"), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            //ON ACTION CODE HERE
            System.out.println("TEST 1 CLICKED!");
        }
    }));
    myTable.getItems().add(new Item("Test 2", "Test 2", new Button("Test 2"), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            //ON ACTION CODE HERE
            System.out.println("TEST 2 BUTTON CLICKED");
        }
    }));
}
```

And the Item class:

```
public class Item {

    public String column1, column2;
    public Button button;

    public Item(String column1, String column2, Button b) {
        this.column1 = column1;
        this.column2 = column2;
        button = b;
    }
}
```

Proof it works:
[image: Proof]

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the Button extends `TableCell<GuiObject, Boolean>`, not  `TableColumn<GuiObject, Boolean>`

Comment: I added lots of extra code that adds a button to the third column. I borrowed some code from another question

Comment: No, I don't understand couple of things. Firstly, what is freqTable? Second, where do you set the button passed by the parameter? You have a StackPane but you don't attach it to anything. And you never assign a new value to addButton.

Comment: It should look like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kX1RR.png

I want to basically have a delete button next to each row, so that I can delete the row from the table and then at the bottom to have one row filled with "<new>" for each fields and next to this row I want to have an add button so that I can add this row to the list.

Comment: Look at updated answer, i wrote something new especially for you i hope it works. it definitely works for me

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Do you have an idea how to get the row for the button clicked?

Comment: Glad it works now! Try doing Item selectedItem = (Item) myTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

Comment: No, this would retrieve the row I have already clicked on, not the button itself. If you don't have selected row, I get `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my final issue thanks to the code from Cobbles. I simply added a method `addAddButton()` which adds a button for new row and provides the functionality for the existing objects of type Item:

```
private void addAddButton() {
        Button b = new Button(" + ");
        final Item item = new Item(="<new>",
                "<new>", b);
        b.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                Button deleteButton = new Button(" - ");
                deleteButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                        selectedItems.remove(item); // a predefined list of selected items
                        myTable.getItems().clear();
                        for (Item current : selectedItems) {
                            myTable.getItems().add(current);
                        }
                        addAddButton();
                    }
                });
                item.setButton(deleteButton);
                selectedItems.add(item);

                myTable.getItems().clear();
                for (Item current : selectedItems) {
                    myTable.getItems().add(current);
                }
                addAddButton();
            }
        });

        tableAvailabilites.getItems().add(ga1);
    }
```

It is not super efficient yet, but it is working!